# Update UI via handler on GCM onMessageReceived

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-messaging, handler, android-handler

A litte question. How I have to call the handler from an other class.

From MainActivity I call "myHandler.post(myRunnable);", but I have no idea how to call...

thanks for our answer!

Main:

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mMeldungTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MeldungTextView);
        mMeldungTextView.setText("click!");
        mp.start();
    }
};
```

OnReceive:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
//public TextView mMeldungTextView;


// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    MainActivity.msg = message;

    sendNotification(message);
    // I want to call handler in MainActivity at this point...
---> myHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send an intent to your activity from onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) with a String extra which will be message.

In your activity handle the intent and send message to your handler.

Comment: Hello, is this the right way? I want only to send a message internal the application. Is there a way to Call the handler in the main activity?

Comment: That is the right way as per my knowledge. You shouldn't access activity directly from the service. Infact a more proper way of doing that is having a backend singleton controller class which has the handler and the handler class then taking further action based on your gcm message data

Comment: You can use BroadcastReceiver and LocalBroadcastManager to send the intent to your listening activity. See an example of broadcasting in this GCM sample https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L76